Receiving bad request when trying to fetch an api in nextjs using nextAuth

when i am trying to register, i am receiving a bad request 404. api url path is correct as well.
i am using nextAuth for authentication. here's the github link. navigate to pages/api/register.
what's the issue? i guess everything is correct. how to fetch the api ?
